# How to use for loop together with stat command in lix shell?

Tags: shell

I wanted to use the stat command to automate so that the loop would bring in the information for each file in the directory.

Example:
`$ for file in *; do stat file; done`

Output for all files in the directory:

```
Arquivo: `index.htm '
Tamanho: 17137 Blocos: 40 Bloco IO: 8192 arquivo regular
Equipamento: 8h / 8d Inode: 23161443 Links: 1
Acesso: (0644 / -rw-r - r--) 
Uid: (17433 / comphope) Gid: (32 / www)
Acesso: 2007-04-03 09: 20: 18.000000000 -0600
Modificar: 2007-04-01 23: 13: 05.000000000 -0600
Alteração: 02-04-2007 
16: 36: 21.000000000 -0600
```

I would be very grateful if you can help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put a `$` in front of the variable and enclose it in double quotes so that it also works for file names with spaces.

```
for file in *; do stat "$file"; done
```

Comment: Always worth a short follow-up on enclosing variables in double-quotes to prevent *"word-splitting"* (default: on whitespace control by `IFS` - the *Internal Field Separator*) That way, if the OP searches for additional information they have the correct terminology to use. (I know what you meant, but for others who visit the answer, they may not) Not a complaint or ding, just a bit of helpful advise. I like the username, better than `chmod 1xxx`.